# Flask library is no longer accessible from http even though the py is still alive and working

Tags: python, flask

Im using the flask library with python to create a web interface.

The py is supposed to be running indefinitely (it get data every 30 min from the DB , do some operations and send the dataframe as json on a certain myroute)

Im using:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5055, debug=True)
```

The problem is that after a while , if I run http://myapp:5055/myroute I will get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
if I run lsof -i tcp:5055 shows that no app is using this port.
However the .py logs that I have in the code are indicating that the code is working fine (its fetching data and adjusting it)

Any clue on how to debug further?

Comment: Which WebServer do you use? The build-in Flask Webserver? UWSGI? Apache?

Comment: I guess the build-in Flask Webserver
The server was already there configured I just added a py code using the flask library. Im still new at this, is there a way to know

Comment: Are you running it on a virtual machine?

Comment: No on a linux server

Comment: Add logging verbosity and traces to your Flask app http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/logging/ and use `curl -v` and other appropriate options to get more information.
Apart from this, Its somehow strange to use Flask (or any Web framework) for pure data processing, but you probably have a good reason for this.

Comment: Flask uses the standard logging. And as I mentionned the logs are indicating that the code is working. Its just that the web interface is not.
Some more context on why Im using Flask:after the data is processed to the route, Im doing pivot tables and graphes with javascript in my html page.